# How to use checkpatch.pl script for our own c files to validate coding style

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I have written one sample chardriver.
I want to verify that coding style is matching with linux kernel coding style or not.

### I did this:

root@vkalyanam-Lenovo-B41-80:~/linux/scripts# ./checkpatch.pl --no-tree --fix mychardriver.c

ERROR: Does not appear to be a unified-diff format patch

total: 1 errors, 0 warnings, 0 lines checked

mychardriver.c has style problems, please review.

NOTE: If any of the errors are false positives, please report

### them to the maintainer, see CHECKPATCH in MAINTAINERS.

Could you help me to resolve above error about unified-diff format patch.
My exact requirement is to validate my own char driver file is matching with linux kernel coding style or not.

Answer (score 7):

By default checkpatch utility checks if a patch is well formated and conforms to Linux Kernel Coding Style Rules. 
If you want to check a file instead of a patch, you need to use -f option.
If your file is not located in a regular kernel tree, you need --no-tree option.
So `./checkpatch.pl -f --no-tree mychardriver.c` should do the job.

Answer (score 4):

To use checkpatch.pl script to validate your own source files:

./checkpatch.pl --no-tree -f sourcefile

This will help you to validate your own c files.